# How can I prevent multiple requests at the same time in NodeJS and Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, server, backend

I have an old project I built with node js and MongoDB, it is a fintech application. I recently noticed that I can trick the system by trying to withdraw the same value twice using two separate clients at the same time.

For instance, I have a balance of 10K units, Whenever I try a withdrawal of 10k on two different clients at the same time, both requests end up successful. I believe this is happening because as at the processing of both requests, the user still has a balance of 10K, therefore, making both requests valid

I have been searching the internet for a possible solution to this but I can't seem to find anything useful (I basically don't know the right keyword to search). Is there a way can block other requests from being processed on the server or DB until the other first one resolves?

This is what my code looks like

```
//Code checks if the account number is valid
 const accountValidation = await handleBankAccountVerification(account_no, bank);
    if(accountValidation.status === 'error' || !accountValidation.data) return res.status(400).send(accountValidation);

//Check if balance is sufficient
  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id)
  if(user.balance < amount) return res.status(400).send({message:"Insufficient balance!"})

const payWithManual = async (user, account_name) =>{
        try{
            //Update User DB balance
            const task = new Fawn.Task()
            
            const data = req.body
            data.status = "pending"
            data.balance = user.balance
            data.account_name = account_name || ''
            data.user = req.user._id
            const {error} = validatePayment(data);
            if(error) return res.status(400).send({message:error.details[0].message})

            const result = await task.update("users",{_id:req.user._id}, {balance:user.balance - amount}) //result will be {_id: someMongoId, name: {full: "Brody Obi"}}
            .save("payments", data )
            .save("transactions", {
                ...transaction,
                action_id:{$ojFuture: "1._id"},
                balance_before:user.balance,
                balance_after:user.balance - amount,
            })
            .run({useMongoose: true})
            const date = dayjs()

            const payload = {
                "country":"NG"
            }
            const response = await flw.Bank.country(payload)
            
            bankName = response.data.filter(item =>{
                return item.code === bank
            })
            
            const html = WithdrawTemplate(amount,user.balance - amount,date.format("hh:mmA MMM DD, YYYY"),account_no, response ? bankName[0].name : null )
            const adminHtml = WithdrawNotificationTemplate(user.email,amount,user.balance - amount,date.format("hh:mmA MMM DD, YYYY"),account_no, response ? bankName[0].name : null )
            const email = await user.sendEmailToUser(`Your made a withdraw`, html, user.email)
            const emailAdmin = await user.sendEmailToUser(`A user is requesting withdrawal`, adminHtml, config.get('NOTIFICATION_EMAIL'))
            
            return res.status(200).send({message:"Fund has been sent to account you provided!", result:result[1]._id})
            return res.status(200).send({message:"Success"})
        }
        catch(e){
            res.status(400).send(e)
    
        }
    }

    const account_name = accountValidation.data.data.account_name;
    await payWithManual(user, account_name)
```

I am running on nodejs version v14.17.6 and mongoose v5.9.9

Comment: Blocking other request would create a queue, just imagine ten people doing different requests, the tenth person would need to wait for the others to get their information or post data to be excepted. If you've set up the connection correctly, CRUD Operations should work without a hitch.

https://learn.mongodb.com/learn/course/mongodb-crud-operations-in-nodejs/lesson-5-deleting-documents-in-nodejs-applications/learn?page=2

Comment: Yeah, all CRUD operations work as expected, but the issue I am having is that a user can withdraw more than his balance by processing a single request multiple times from different clients (browser, incognito), i.e he can request a withdrawal of 10K multiple times as far as he does it at the same time from different clients (incognito tabs).

Comment: Add the current/expected balance (prior to the transaction) to the query conditions for the update. If a concurrent request modifies the value first, the document will no longer match for this (second) request and therefore the document won't be incorrectly updated a second time

Comment: @user20042973 I just edited my question to include what my code looks like, can you please indicate how I can go about this?

Comment: Ooof! there are so many wrong things in that code dude, const's that get to nowhere, double returns etc. You might wanna revamp your code to make it functional.

Comment: You can use something called a 'transaction lock'. (write or read lock depending on the situation).
If a transaction needs to update or write to item X, the lock must restrict all other transactions and provide exclusive access to the current transaction. Thus, these locks are also known as exclusive locks.